# Minify multiple javascript files with webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I am new to webpack. I wish to minify all files in a folder to single js using webpack. I don't wish to add all files name manually one by one in entry section.

I am quite sure there must be a clean way for that but I am unable to find that on google or webpack official documentation.

Please help.

Comment: Do those files import each other?

Comment: Those are plain old javascript files. Have references of common functions but not exactly ES6 import statements with a common starting script.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
const glob = require("glob");

module.exports = {
    entry: glob.sync("./src/*.js")
};
```