# Using Webpack to minify jQuery files & update references into HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, babeljs, uglifyjs

I've approx 10 individual pages, with library references & custom jQuery codes included in each HTML files separately.

1. Can Webpack be used for minifying Javascript files.
2. Transform references of .js files into .min.js in all my HTMLs during build?

All search references w.r.t webpack points out to ES6 modules which are kick-started using index.js, I've got none :-(

Comment: Are you using Node or NPM command for minify each JS file?

Comment: solution for your problem seems to explain here  https://dev.to/mariorodeghiero/multiple-html-files-with-htmlwebpackplugin-19bf

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `script-loader` and `terser-webpack-plugin` in the optimization
to minimize your files.

But you will end up with too much configuration for a small task. This is not worth the effort.

I would recommend using some npm plugin like

[webpack-merge-and-include-globally](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge-and-include-globally)

Or just use `cpx` to copy files to dist and transform them while copying.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Can Webpack be used for minifying Javascript files.

Yes, you can resolve files by many ways, ES6 modules, alias, extensions, and then use any the available plugins to minify it.

Here a couple of ways to config the resolution part: 
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

```
// alias
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '~': Path.resolve(__dirname, '/src')
    }
},

// module
resolve: {
    modules: [SRC_DIR, '/src']
},

// extension
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.json']
},
```

And then for minification: 
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/ 
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
            }),
        ],
    },
};

const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
            }),
        ],
    },
};
```

You will need a compiler for your .js files so you can use babel for it

```
module:{
    rules:[
    {
        test:/\.js$/,
        use:['babel-loader']
    }
    ]
}
```

> 2. Transform references of .js files into .min.js in all my HTMLs during build?

To create many outputs you should consider checking this 
[Minify multiple javascript files with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42710170/minify-multiple-javascript-files-with-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like JScompress : https://jscompress.com/

JSCompress minify and compress all your code into single javascript code.

Then you can provide a single JS File to your HTML such as bundle.[crc32_signature].js

Moreover, you could manage HTML caching to reduce your network bottleneck.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Cache